# Как сделать правильно запрос к базе Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Я хочу сделать правильно фильтр по цене, но выдаёт ошибку.

В таблице есть 2 поля с ценами `price_weekend_max` и `price_weekend_max_comm`. При выводе этих цен я их прибавляю, т.е `$c->price_weekend_max + $c->price_weekend_max_comm` и получается одна единая цена по которой я пытаюсь сделать фильтр.

Фильтр работает по следующему принципу: обычный ползунок от одной цены до к другой *мин\макс* передаются цены в метод и там я хочу фильтровать данные запросом.

```
$filtered_items = Cottage::orderBy('priority', 'desc');
$filtered_items = $filtered_items
                    ->where('price_weekend_max + price_weekend_max_comm','>=', $data['price_from']) 
                    ->where('price_weekend_max + price_weekend_max_comm','<=', $data['price_to']);
```

При запросе получается ошибка:

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '47000' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `cottages_new` where `persons_min` >= 1 and `47000` >= 0 and `47000` <= 0 and `publish` = 1)
```

Comment: `where('тут должно быть название колонки', ...)->get()`, а у Вас не название, а наверное значение..

Comment: Да, это значение, вот и не могу понять как правильно сделать

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на ошибку. MySQL не может найти в БД колонку `47000`, поэтому того кода, что Вы показали, явно недостаточно для решения задачи. Посмотрите, что в себе хранит `$data`, сделайте дебаг sql-запроса.

Удобный пакет для дебага: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: в $data хранится сумма которая передаётся с формы фильтра, мне надо сплюсовать суммы с этих двух колонок и найти в базе записи которые в диапазоне сумм которые поступили с $data['price_from'] и $data['price_to']

Answer (score 0):

Должно сработать:

```
$filtered_items = Cottage::orderBy('priority', 'desc');
$filtered_items = $filtered_items
                    ->where((int)'price_weekend_max + price_weekend_max_comm','>=', $data['price_from']) 
                    ->where((int)'price_weekend_max + price_weekend_max_comm','<=', $data['price_to']);
```

Comment: не сработало ошибка SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `cottages_new` where `persons_min` >= 1 and `0` >= 0 and `0` <= 26000 and `publish` = 1)